When exactly does a differential equation have no degree?
I am currently taking a Differential Equations class for my Computer Engineering program and we're still at the introduction of the basic concepts for DEs. I am genuinely confused as to whether what exactly is the criteria for a differential equation to have "no degree". In our university's DE book, it's stated, and I quote,

The differential equations $y'^(1/2) - 2y = x$,
$(d^2y/dx^2)+2e^y(dy/dx)=1$, $y'+sin(y)=0$, and $y'^(1/2) - 2y = x$
have no degree as it cannot be written as polynomial in the unknown
function y.

now, I can grasp math concepts but not in the deepest of sense most of the time and I was confused as to what makes a polynomial aside from each variable in the terms of an equation is a positive whole numbers. I then went to the internet and there are conflicting points when it comes to the "no degree" thing: others saying we should manipulate the equations first and try to get rid of the radicals and differentials inside transcendental functions (which I thought conflicts with the examples in our book), others say is there's no differential inside a transcendental function then there's a degree (which then again conflicts with the example in our book). I also found someone saying that in equations like $$sin(d^3y/dx^3)=(dy/dx)+x$$ in which the highest differential is inside a transcendental function, we must just ignore them and go for differentials that are not in a transcendental function, in this case the dy/dx term, making the order and degree 1. I am just generally confused and if anyone can make light of this for me I would really REALLY appreciate it.
In the following equations (these are non-linear DEs), do these have degrees or not? :
$$ yy''+2xy'-3y=3x-7$$ $$ (y''')^3+2xy''-3y^2y'=3x$$ $$ (dy/dt)+y/(3t-1)=y^2(t^2-1)$$

It is the normal case that differential equations have no structure that allows to assign a degree.
A graded structure for some associated class of ODE should serve some purpose, otherwise it is not worth spending time on it. Unfortunately, in most circumstances the purpose is "provide students with classification exercises", where the intent is not so much to work towards the solutions of the DE, but to measure the students capabilities to parse and understand expressions.
There are some circumstances where a graded structure is actually mathematically useful. On is in implicit differential equations that are polynomial (at least) in the highest occuring derivative. Then the degree tells how many different solutions can pass through the same initial point. If restricted to the real domain, the degree is an upper bound for the number of real solutions
